# These pages showing url too long and poorly formatted in uber suggest in terms of seo.How to solve this problem

Tags: seo, wordpress, pagination, seo-audit

[image]

I have a word press site and doing SEO with yoast premium plugin all other SEO related issue are solved but these pagination problem is a headache I search the internet but didn't find solution for that

Comment: Yet another useless tool. Don't worry about what that tools says. Get a Google Search Console account and focus on any feedback you see there.

Comment: I didn't know that Neil had a full SEO dashboard product, but it doesn't surprise me. As John mentioned, there is no obvious problem here. The tool is probably wrong. The URLs in your screenshot are rather short, would you not agree?

Comment: Yes I think you are right